# Access: Select multiple records to print report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to design a form where I can select multiple records and on button click open the report with the selected records IDs.

I am thinking maybe make a continuous form with an added unbound check box control where the user selects the appropriate records they want to display in the report. I am unsure how to later read this into a do.cmd OpenReport criteria property.
If there is an easier way to this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a column to your dataset where they can determine which rows to print?  You could add a printMe Y/N column, for example, and then use that field value to limit the rows for the report.

Comment: I can't add a field because the "recordset is not updatable".

Comment: You have to add it to the form's underlying recordsource, not within the form itself.

Comment: I mean the query I used as the record source is not updateable.

Comment: If you can't edit the tables in your query to end up with an updateable recordsource, you can either create another table with key values into your existing query or write your existing query records into a new table with the printMe column and base your form on that recordset.

Comment: If I copy the results of the query to another table with the printMe field, how can I avoid mixing with other query results as this will be used by other users at the same time. The back-end is on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Wasn't sure if multi-user access was a concern of yours, but if it is, you can use their login info to keep their marks separate or generate an ID when you create the report.

Comment: At which moment should this data be deleted?

Comment: After the report's finished loading, or before the report runs, if you're using a login ID.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135546 or http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html. Another approach you could take is create a temporary table that contains a single field for your record ID. Using the code from the links, fill the temporary table with the record IDs that have been selected. Then all you need to do is change the query that drives your report to do an inner join with the temporary table.